# How do I get my Android tablet on my network without getting stuck in a reboot loop?

Tags: boot-loop, stock-android, troubleshooting

I recently acquired an Android tablet PC (this thing: http://yourfirstsmartphone.com/android-tablet-pc/). I have not altered it at all from the factory fresh settings (in fact in attempt to solve the problem I'm having I did a factory reset) and yet whenever I attempt to connect to a wifi network the tablet will reboot, the os will load and work for about 30 seconds, then it will reboot again and the same thing just goes on endlessly. It's running on android version 4.4.2, firmware is version 4.4v2.0, kernel version 3.4.39 Ipp@Android #252. What do I do?

Comment: The website you've linked to is just a photo. It doesn't tell us anything about the device.

Comment: what else is there to tell about the device other than the model, the version of the android os it runs on, the firmware version, and the kernel version? What else do you need?

Comment: The model would be a good start, but the photo looks like an unbranded one, so you might not be able to get help anyway.

Comment: The model is literally called "Android Tablet PC"... It's a Chinese thing I think... the user instructional book is very badly translated. Here is a video review on the device, however the device reviewed is using a different os. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os2RBn2h0k8

Answer (score 0):

> What do I do?

Send it back. You've bought a computer that doesn't work, and fixing the problem is the responsibility of the vendor.

Comment: I didn't say I bought it. I said I acquired it, I won it in a contest. Can't return it. Besides my pride as a nerd is at stake, if I can't fix my own device than what kind of nerd am I? (not a very good one that's for sure)

Comment: @WorryRick nerd pride +1, good one. You'll have to find out what the chipset is. From there you can Google the chipset and hopefully find a forum relating to you device. It sounds like firmware is borked. Good luck.